# {N} 6.0 migration: partial .scss files are now compiled separately

Tags: sass, nativescript

I’m upgrading my project to {N} 6.0 and had been using the nativescript-dev-sass plug-in.  I realize the .scss files are now handled by WebPack, but I have a partial file (i.e., begins with an underscore since it’s @imported by other, platform-specific files), but I’m getting a build error stating that the variables referenced in the file are not defined, which suggests the file is being processed by the scss transpiler as a stand-alone file.

```
WARNING in ./views/_app-config-page.common.scss
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

  font-size: $apphdr-font-size;  
            ^
      Undefined variable: "$apphdr-font-size".
      in /Users/david/Documents/NativeScriptProjects/cflclt/app/views/_app-config-page.common.scss (line 36, column 14)
 @ \b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$ (. sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$) ./views/_app-config-page.common.scss
 @ ./app.js
```

Is there something extra or different I need to do for partial .scss files in {N} 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

The file name was the problem, or at least the cause of the error.  When I changed the file name from

```
_app-config-page.common.scss
```

to

```
_app-config-page-common.scss
```

the build error went away.  It appears this is a difference between WebPack's sass-loader and the previously used, now deprecated, nativescript-dev-sass plug-in.